# TFLiteConverter throws KeyError: 'cond_1_input_1_0'

Tags: tensorflow2.0, python-3.8, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert a function with the `TFLiteConverter`:

```
logger = logging

enable_eager_in_debug()

model_dir = '/data/asr/models/experiments/vanilla-char'
hparams_fp = os.path.join(model_dir, 'hparams.json')
latest_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir)
assert latest_checkpoint, f'No checkpoints found in {model_dir}'

with open(hparams_fp) as f:
    hparams = json.load(f)

model = RNNModel(**hparams)
ckpt = model.load_weights(latest_checkpoint)
ckpt.expect_partial()

model = ModelTflite(model)

logger.info('Converting to tflite-model')
concrete_fn = model.predict.get_concrete_function()
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_fn])
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

logger.info('Writing model.tflite')
with open(os.path.join(model_dir, 'model.tflite'), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)

logger.info('All done.')
```

The model is a wrapped class (work in progress) that just creates a `@tf.function` for me to export:

```py
class ModelTflite:

    def __init__(self, model: RNNModel):
        self.model = model
        mel_bins = 80
        max_input_len = 500

        @tf.function(
            experimental_relax_shapes=True,
            input_signature=(
                tf.TensorSpec(shape=[1, max_input_len, mel_bins], dtype=tf.float32),
            )
        )
        def predict_stream(inputs: tf.Tensor):
            return self.model.infer(inputs)

        self.predict = predict_stream
```

However, the conversion aborts with the following error:

```
...
2020-08-07 16:29:30.327955: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:797] Optimization results for grappler item: cond_1_false_12473
2020-08-07 16:29:30.327960: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:799]   function_optimizer: function_optimizer did nothing. time = 0ms.
2020-08-07 16:29:30.327965: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:799]   function_optimizer: function_optimizer did nothing. time = 0.001ms.
2020-08-07 16:29:30.327970: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:797] Optimization results for grappler item: TensorArrayV2Write_cond_false_12448
2020-08-07 16:29:30.327975: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:799]   function_optimizer: function_optimizer did nothing. time = 0ms.
2020-08-07 16:29:30.327980: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:799]   function_optimizer: function_optimizer did nothing. time = 0ms.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sfalk/tmp/speech-v2/asr/bin/demo.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/sfalk/tmp/speech-v2/asr/bin/demo.py", line 44, in main
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
  File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/asr2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 458, in convert
    _convert_to_constants.convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph(
  File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/asr2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py", line 705, in convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph
    graph_def, converted_inputs = _convert_variables_to_constants_v2_impl(
  File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/asr2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py", line 460, in _convert_variables_to_constants_v2_impl
    function_data = _get_control_flow_function_data(
  File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/asr2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py", line 286, in _get_control_flow_function_data
    arg_types[idx] = get_resource_type(node.input[idx + 1])
  File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/asr2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py", line 259, in get_resource_type
    node_name = get_source_node_name_through_identities(node_name)
  File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/asr2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py", line 254, in get_source_node_name_through_identities
    while name_to_node[node_name].op == "Identity":
KeyError: 'cond_1_input_1_0'
```

I don't understand quite why this is failing.

Is there a way to get more information? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

1. Use an updated version of TensorFlow (>=2.3)
2. Look for "KeyError TensorFlow Lite Converter" on Google - you should find links to github issues with suggested solutions. g: Try the solution listed here - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26672#issuecomment-472519970
3. If this is an RNN model, refer to the [TFLite RNN documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/rnn).
4. If this is an RNN model, create a Github issue - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new?labels=TFLiteConverter&template=60-tflite-converter-issue.md and follow RNN specific instructions as mentioned in this link.